# 'Anyobject' is not convertible to 'UICollectionViewCell'

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm new to the swift language. I'm trying to use CollectionView but I'm running into some trouble. Here's the [tutorial](https://youtu.be/UH3HoPar_xg?t=387) I am following.

but I can't get past 6:20 since this error message appears:

> 'Anyobject' is not convertible to 'UICollectionViewCell'

The only thing I did different from the tutorial is that I did not delete ViewerController class to change it to CollectionViewController.

Instead, I created a new class called CollectionViewController and followed step by step from then on. I did this because my CollectionViewController is to be added to an existing project and I don't want it to be the initial View Controller.

Let me know if you want to see my code. 
I only didn't paste it for simplicity

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
```

difference it `as` or `as!`. It's because of swift version.

Comment: Swift editor did suggest that the first time and I did so but the error just changed. This time it worked perfectly. OK thank you very much mr Ryosuke

Comment: Stack Overflow has a great way of letting other people know that an answer worked, if you click on the Checkmark then people who come to this question for help in the future will know that this answer worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Xcode 6.3 or later, you will need to use as! rather than as.

That's because Swift 1.2 change the downcast from as to as! or as?

To look detail you can see [this](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23)